# Checking Against an Array of Values in my Angular 2 App

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to figure out how to pull data from an array of values, rather than a single value while binding using [(ngModel)] in my Angular 2 app. What I currently have works fine with a single value like this. The single value that's being checked to pull data from the db is whatever's assigned to "value", in this case "staff":

```
<div class="radio">
    <input type="radio" value="staff" name="category" [(ngModel)]="category"> Staff
</div>
```

This works as expected with a single value. However, one of the values I'm checking against isn't just a single value, but rather an array of values - something like ['advertising', 'accounting', 'adminstration'];

I tried handling this like this in my component:

```
staff = [
{ value: 1, name: 'advertising' },
{ value: 2, name: 'administration' },
{ value: 3, name: 'accounting' }
];
```

And then in my view I tried binding to this "staff" array like this:

```
<div class="radio">
    <input type="radio" [value]="staff.value" name="category" [(ngModel)]="category"> Staff
</div>
```

... but this didn't work. How would I check against an array of values rather than a single value?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do a `*ngFor` and an `*ngIf.`

Loop through the array and when the array has value=staff then output.

probably change the array name to staffs

`*ngFor="let staff of staffs`

`*ngIf="value=staff.value`

Comment: I think I'd only use *ngFor if I wanted to render a list to the view. But I don't want to do that, I just want an array of values checked.